# Spring Boot - How to associate a request with a particular user?

Tags: spring-boot, session, multiple-users

I have a spring boot application and now i need to return specific information for each user that makes an http request. How can i achieve this? I have to scale this up so multiple instances of the application must be consider.
For example..
In the fornt end an user is logged in, for each request this user makes, i have to return his proper information.
If another user is logged, and makes a request at the same time, he also gets his own information.

I was thinking that i can achive this by including user id in each request but don´t know if this is the proper way.

Comment: You should use Spring security to achieve that: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security

Comment: Also I suggest your question is more inclined towards session maintenance (or profile management) while, spring boot, which helps create microservices based on REST API architecture, each request is to be treated a new one (Basically stateless communication which HTTP protocol adheres to) where in each request will either GET,PUT, POST, PATCH a resource